# Non-spicy substitute for chili peppers when making a Thai curry paste from scratch

Tags: substitutions, curry, thai-cuisine

I'm making a green Thai curry paste from scratch. I'm very happy with the recipe, and I've made it with much success in the past, but today I am cooking for someone who can't take much heat. Or well, only very little; I can put a single *capsicum annuum* ('standard' red chili pepper?) in a  dish for 4, let's say.

But the recipe calls for 3 tablespoons of green bird's eye chilies. That's definitely going to be too hot, even if I de-seed and trim the insides. However, a significant part of the paste comes from these (there's about 11 Tbsp of ingredients in total, so 1/3th to 1/4th is the chilies) and leaving them out entirely probably doesn't do it any favour.

So my question is, what would you replace them with? I could get a green bell pepper, but I imagine that'd be quite watery. I also have access to jalapenos, which are a bit milder (and green, as far as that matters) but I imagine could still get quite spicy. Or perhaps I do leave them out after all. What would you go for?

Comment: Honestly I would be tempted to just  leave it out and invite the folks that want the heat to add some chili paste (of some sort...) at the table.

Comment: Texas A&M Jalapenos look like large, shiny Jalapenos, but lack most of the heat. Cut them in half, scrape out the seed membranes and you should end up with something people have trouble telling from a standard bell pepper. For a *little* warmth, and a more complex flavor, go with Anaheim or Hatch peppers. Again, scrape out seeds and membranes.

Comment: The bird's eye peppers don't add much fragrance, just heat.  The other ingredients in Thai curry are all very potent aromatics that totally overpower any subtle elements the chilis provide.  If you want it less spicy, just use fewer or leave them out.  They don't need a substitute - just omit.  You'll end up with less paste.  That's how it goes - scale the rest of the recipe if you want more.

Comment: @J... A green bird's eye does have a quite specific flavour, aside from the heat. You could substitute maybe a Jalapeño or Fresno & get a similar flavour with reduced [though still very noticeable] heat. A bell-pepper just tastes 'different' as would a Habañero or Scotch Bonnet [again, ignoring the heat], or indeed any red chilli when a green was needed. There's a definite need for the 'green chilli' flavour in a Thai green paste that I think would be missed if it wasn't there at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin I suppose it's a matter of taste.  I find with Thai paste the other aromatics are much more dominant - the sharp pine aromas from the galangal, the brightness from the lemongrass and lime leaf, the pungency of the fermented shrimp and fish sauce, garlic, shallots, white pepper.  Underneath all of that it's hard to pick out a contribution from the chilis, I find.  It's not like a west-indian sauce, for example, which is also very hot, but has dominant flavours from the scotch bonnet that can't be easily substituted.  The bird's eye has a much more subtle fragrance, imo.

Comment: @J... Interesting that you keep returning to 'fragrance'. I don't consider the green chilli to provide much fragrance at all, but I do consider it provides flavour. I'm reasonably sure I wouldn't be able to spot simply by smell if the chilli had been left out or substituted, against the pungency of coriander [cilantro] etc, but i would once I tasted it. And my nose isn't that bad - I can smell if boiling potatoes have been salted or not ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin  Beyond basic salt/sweet/sour/umami/bitter (true "flavours"), fragrance really *is* what makes up most "flavour", if you want to use that word.   I mean it to describe both when eating or just smelling.  Try eating with your nose plugged some day - you lose about 90% of your "flavour" discrimination, I'd say.  To be fair, I've never made green curry with little to no chili so I don't know for certain to what degree you'd miss that component.

Comment: @Tetsujin Certainly the chili-phobe diner will not have a frame of reference for comparison and I think the resulting dish would retain the core flavour profile of "Thai Curry" - it just won't be "Red Curry" or "Green Curry", but something like a "White Curry", which would be about as different from either as they are from each other (which isn't terribly alot, imo).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me take a wild swing -

I think trying to generate the volume required by using jalapeños would be too hot for your friend & you're right that a regular capsicum/bell pepper wouldn't have enough flavour to water ratio. Also 'bell peppers' don't taste like chillies.

How about [Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_wax_pepper) or [Banana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_pepper) peppers?

Now, this is quite a variable & may depend on where you live as to which type you can access. Here in North London I can choose from 3 varieties without going more than 50m from my front door - from the the fat 'triangular' ones like giant fresnos with very smooth skin which are very cool, to the skinny ones about 20cm long with a 'lumpy' skin, which would be the type I would aim for.
Though they are generically known as Hungarian, [& of course, could actually be grown anywhere] they are likely to be commonly found in Turkish stores - local availability of course not guaranteed.

They taste like 'chilli' not like 'bell peppers' but they really don't have too much kick to them. They would generate the flavour without too much heat, but not sufficient colour, so you could perhaps trick some extra coriander [cilantro] into your paste to deepen the green.

From comments - though I wouldn't bother for myself, you can keep the heat down still further by not using the seeds or inner 'whiter' membranes.

Comment: Chipotle peppers may work too, they're a little spicy but have a nice smoky and somewhat sweet flavor.

Comment: I've never tried this, so it's a wild suggestion, but I believe you could also get away with bell peppers if you slice them finely (to almost a pulp), use some salt to draw out the moisture and let it reduce by frying with a very small amount of oil on low heat.

Comment: There *are* cultivars of Banana peppers that go far past 500 Scoville units. Test before you use these. Try eating a seed and a bit of the membrane holding it.

Comment: @BruceWayne - aside from the fact that they would be far too hot, they are after all jalapeños ...and dried.. and red... and smoked... smoked red chillies in a Thai green curry?? Just no.

Comment: @Tetsujin Agreed.  A fresh green poblano might be a reasonable substitute, although you do occasionally get a "surprise" poblano which is much hotter than you might typically expect.

Comment: @J... I'll have to leave that one to your call - I've never even seen a fresh poblano :) Simply not available in the UK.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, probably not at Tesco or Sainsbury, but you can probably get them from specialty grocers in larger cities or there's always the online option.

Comment: @J... You might be surprised. "Exotic" fresh food imports & local growers are heavily influenced, of course, by local immigrant demand initially... so, lots of 'Indian' SE Asian, 'Turkish,' mediterranean, EU, a good recent build up of African ... but Mexican, really not so much. In recent years I can now source [expensive, £14 a kilo] fresh tomatillos & even Asda sell padrons periodically, but fresh 'Mexican' is really not easy. A lot of the 'boutique' online retailers seem to specialise in 'blow your head off' varieties. Dried I can get anything these days, but fresh is not yet so easy.

Answer (score 3):

I do this a lot (mostly red curries though) using oven-dried bell peppers, or the variety that is sold here as "sweet pointy peppers". To dry the peppers, I halve and deseed them and put them in a convection oven at 90°C for about 3 hours. They don't have to be dehydrated completely, just semi-dry (like sun dried tomatoes) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should get our hands on Kashmiri Red Chilli which is easily available in powder form at Indian stores, however it shouldn't be impossible to find whole dried ones. It has the typical red chilli flavor without any considerable heat.

Alternatively, you can try tomato puree but it will not tasye the same.

Comment: Interesting! The Kashmiri red chili powder I have at home has considerable heat. Maybe the labeling is off on that one.

Comment: @user129412 No, it's just that spice tolerance runs on a logarithmic scale.  Something with "almost no heat" to one person can be raging hot to another.  Furthermore, each of those people can probably find someone they could say the same about for a tier up or down in spice as well.  This is why eastern restaurants in the west are so pathetic with the amount of spice they use - the lowest common denominator is so incredibly sensitive to capsaicin that they just don't risk any more than a whiff.  I mean, I've seen people tear up eating chicken paprikash, if you can believe it.  Go figure.

Comment: @J... That is true of course. I do consider myself to have a somewhat high tolerance for heat though (I cook with scotch bonnets without deseeding them, which doesn't make me a world champion but I wouldn't recommend it to most of my friends), and the stuff I have with that name is definitely spicy to most standards. I wouldn't put it in a different order of magnitude from birds eye chillies, which are the ones I am looking to replace in the recipe. So I'd attribute it to me or Love Bites having something that is not standard.

Comment: @user129412 Fair enough.  Could just be a different source.  Even genetically identical peppers can range from mild to crazy hot depending on growing conditions, etc.  Kashmiri pepper grown in Kashmir will certainly taste different to the same pepper grown on another continent, in a different climate.  True Kashmiri chili powder should be quite on the mild side, though - it is used primarily for colour and flavour in Indian cooking, and not for heat.

Comment: I love Kashmiri Mirch - use it all the time, it's fairly easy to get in the UK... but not in a green curry. For a red chilli substitute, ordinary [unsmoked] paprika is not a million miles away from Mirch, or New Mexico... but again, not for a green curry.

Comment: If you feel that even powdered Kashmiri Chillis are not mild enough for you, then you should get whole dried kashmiri chillies and use it without the seeds. Perhaps you'd like to share which brand of Kashmiri chillies you have?